# mathematical formula in python doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have been learning machine learning in python and currently im studying the basics. Im now studying linear regression and trying to implement some mathematical formulas into python code. I managed to write some formulas successfuly but there is this one im having a hard time with:
(X - Xmeans) * (Y - Ymeans) 
It always gives me an error of "list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64" when I try to print it.

I've tried to look for same cases and their solutions in the web but none of them worked.

```py
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_positions = numpy.array([2,3,4,5,6])
y_positions = numpy.array([4,5,6,5,7])
plt.plot([X_positions], [y_positions], 'ro')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_means = sum(X_positions) / len(X_positions)
y_means = sum(y_positions) / len(y_positions)

plt.plot([X_means], [y_means], 'go')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_minus_X_means = []
y_minus_y_means = []
X_minus_X_means_squared = []

for i in X_positions:
    X_minus_X_means.append(i - X_means)

for i in y_positions:
    y_minus_y_means.append(i - y_means)

for i in X_minus_X_means:
    X_minus_X_means_squared.append(i ** 2)

X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means = []

#HERE IS THE PROBLEM
for i in X_minus_X_means and y_minus_y_means:
   X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means.append(X_minus_X_means[i] * y_minus_y_means[i])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really just use the built-in numpy operations and the vectorized operations when possible.

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_positions = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
y_positions = np.array([4,5,6,5,7])
plt.plot([X_positions], [y_positions], 'ro')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_means = X_positions.mean()
y_means = y_positions.mean()

plt.plot([X_means], [y_means], 'go')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])

X_minus_X_means = X_positions-X_means
y_minus_y_means = y_positions-y_means
X_minus_X_means_squared = X_minus_X_means**2
X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means = X_minus_X_means*y_minus_y_means
```

Comment: Usually, when you use numpy you want to stay away from loops. Most operations on numpy arrays are faster and easier using builtins or vectorized operations (this isn't always the case but a solid generalization to go by when you're getting started).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for i in X_minus_X_means and y_minus_y_means:
```

try to write

```
for i in range(len(X_minus_X_means)):
```

otherwise `i` is not an integer and cannot be used as an index

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the division is yielding a `float` which is causing the index to be a non-integer?

```
X_means = sum(X_positions) / len(X_positions)
```

For integer division in python3, the double slash operator `//` is available:

```
X_means = sum(X_positions) // len(X_positions)
```

You could also use `ceil`, `floor`, `round`, or `int(val)`.

Answer (score 0):

both `X_minus_X_means` and `y_minus_y_means` are list

`y_minus_y_means` contain value

```
[-1.4000000000000004,
 -0.40000000000000036,
 0.5999999999999996,
 -0.40000000000000036,
 1.5999999999999996]
```

so basically inside `for i in X_minus_X_means and y_minus_y_means:` value of `i` calculated in operation is of `type numpy.float64` and inside loop, you are accessing value of `X_minus_X_means` and `y_minus_y_means` using `index` which is  `i` a `float` value

Answer (score 0):

While I completely support and prefer vectorized operations, I think you should know about the function called `zip` which is helpful in situations where you are iterating over two (or more) lists in parallel. So in your case, the problematic part should be changed to the following avoiding any index `i`

```
for x, y in zip(X_minus_X_means, y_minus_y_means):
    X_minus_X_means_times_y_minus_y_means.append(x * y)
```